# cordova admob plugin - missing module

Tags: cordova, admob

I ran in the terminal `cordova plugin add cordova-admob-plus --variable APP_ID_ANDROID=THERE IS MY APP ID`
Instalation went nice but now when I try to

```
import admob from "cordova-admob-plus/www/admob
```

I'm getting error

```
/node_modules/cordova-admob-plus/www/admob.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'cordova' in 'D:\Documents\Programowanie\newcircleriskcordova\client\node_modules\cordova-admob-plus\www'
@ ./node_modules/cordova-admob-plus/www/admob.js 3:16-34
@ ./src/index.js
```

So I tried again to ran `npm install -g cordova` like before, to import admob but  without sucess, the error is same

Did someone had the same problem and fixed it?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I had to run cordova build and then cordova run browser or any other platform